# Cordova camera changes filename after saving to gallery on iOS

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

i am using the cordova camera plugin and saving images to the gallery/photos so they don't delete as prior to this my photos would be saved to the cache and delete quickly enough.
I attach the images i take and save with camera plugin to an email.
What i do is save the ImageURI from the camera function to localstorage to be called again if i resend the email at a later date.
This method works in the short-term and images attach successfully but not after a few hours.
The imageURI of captured images is usually on the format of cdv_photo_001.jpg for example. 
However, the images are saved in photos/gallery and the filenames tend to be normal "IMG_0001.JPG" format and don't attach to the email.

is there a way i can get the actual gallery name while taking a picture.
Ive tried to save the image persistently using some guides but i could never get the moveTo to work.
Anyone any ideas?
Thanks